# Why is the space of $L^p$ (Fourier) multipliers a Banach space? (Stein)

Tags: fourier-analysis, operator-theory, banach-algebras, complete-spaces, littlewood-paley-theory

I am reading Stein's book 'Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions', and he introduces the class $\mathcal{M}_p$ of $L^{\infty}$ multipliers $m$ such that the operator $T_m$ defined for $f\in{L^2}{\cap}{L^p}$ by $\widehat{(T_mf)}(x)=m(x)\hat{f}(x)$ is bounded on $L^p$, endowing the class with the operator norm of $T_m$.

He then states that this class is a Banach algebra, but I can't prove it. If $(m_n)_n$ is a sequence in $\mathcal{M}_p$, we can deduce that $T_{m_n}f\rightarrow{Tf}$ for some $T\in{\mathcal{B}}(L^p,L^p)$ as ${\mathcal{B}}(L^p,L^p)$ is a Banach space. But how can we show that $T$ corresponds to a Fourier multiplier? I think it would be enough to show that $T_{m_n}f\rightarrow{Tf}$ in $L^2$ also, to try and show that $(m_n)_n$ is also Cauchy in $L^{\infty}$ and so has a limit there, but I can't see how to prove this.
Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an argument that at least works for $1 < p < \infty$. We take for granted at the outset that $\mathcal{M}_2 = L^{\infty}$ and so is complete.

**Step 1**

First off, by a duality argument we can show that if $m \in \mathcal{M}_p$, then also $m \in \mathcal{M}_{p'}$, and that the norms are identical. (So these spaces are isomorphic.)

To see this, let $f$ and $g$ be Schwartz functions. Then using Plancherel's theorem, we obtain
$$
\int (T_m f) \overline{g} \, dx
= \int m \hat{f} \overline{\hat{g}} \, d\xi
= \int (T_m \tilde{g}) \overline{\tilde{f}} \, dx,
$$
where $\tilde{f}(x) = \overline{f(-x)}$. So
$$
| (T_m f, g) |
= | (T_m \tilde{g}, \tilde{f}) |
\leq \| T_m \tilde{g} \|_p \| \tilde{f} \|_{p'}
\leq \| m \|_{\mathcal{M}_p} \| g \|_p \| f \|_{p'}.
$$
This shows that $T_m$ is bounded on $L^{p'}$, with an operator norm not more than the operator norm on $L^p$. Inverting the roles of $p$ and $p'$ gives the equality of norms.

**Step 2**

Based on the above, we can extend $T_m$ to an operator on $L^p + L^{p'}$. Complex interpolation then gives us that $\log \| T_m \|_{L^q \to L^q}$ is a convex function of $1/q$, for $q$ between $p$ and $p'$. In particular, the equality of operator norms at the endpoints implies that $\| T_m \|_{L^q \to L^q} \leq \| m \|_{\mathcal{M}_p}$ for $q$ in this range.

**Step 3**

With these preliminaries set, suppose that $(m_n)_n$ is Cauchy in $\mathcal{M}_p \subseteq \mathcal{B}(L^p, L^p)$, with $p \leq 2$. By the norm comparison property in Step 2, it follows that the sequence is also Cauchy in $\mathcal{M}_q$ for all $q$ between $p$ and $p'$, and in particular for $\mathcal{M}_2$. So for each $q$ we can extract a limiting operator $T^{(q)} \in \mathcal{B}(L^q, L^q)$. Since $\mathcal{M}_2 = L^{\infty}$ is complete, we know that $T^{(2)}$ corresponds to a multiplier $m$.

**Step 4**

We now have a candidate multiplier, $m$, and it just remains to show that $T^{(p)}$ corresponds to $T_m$. For this, fix a (Schwartz, or $L^p \cap L^2$) function $f$. Then the sequence $(T_{m_n} f)_n$ converges in $L^p$ to $T^{(p)} f$. The corresponding convergence in $L^2$ to $T^{(2)} f = T_m f$ implies, via Hölder's inequaltiy, that if we restrict the $T_{m_n} f$ to a set $E$ of finite measure, then $T_{m_n} f |_E \to T_m f |_E$ in $L^p$. Piecing together the finite-measure sets, we see that the overall $L^p$ limit $T^{(p)} f$ must be identical to $T_m f$.

**Step 5**

Steps 3 and 4 show that $\mathcal{M}_p$ is complete for $1 < p < 2$. By the isomorphism indicated in Step 1, we also obtain completeness for $2 < p < \infty$.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for thank you! I hadn't thought to use the interpolation theorems. I am not familiar with complex interpolation but used the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem, is this basically the same thing? And can we also deduce in step 1 that \mathcal{M}_1 embeds into \mathcal{M}_{\infty} so use the same proof for the case p=1, but not p=\infty?

Comment: @user294388 You're very welcome! To your first question--the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem is definitely similar in its conclusions to the Riesz-Thorin theorem for complex interpolation (if less so in the method of proof), and it does suffice here. The key point is that the interpolated bounds imply that if $(m_n)_n$ is Cauchy in $\mathcal{M}_p$, it's also Cauchy in $\mathcal{M}_2$.

Comment: To the second question about $\mathcal{M}_1$, and in particular embedding it in $\mathcal{M}_{\infty}$, I'm less sure. My sticking point at the moment is how $\mathcal{M}_{\infty}$ is actually defined: $L^2 \cap L^{\infty}$ isn't dense in $L^{\infty}$, and so the main definition Stein uses would have to be re-worked.

Comment: Actually, strike what I said about $\mathcal{M}_1$ and $\mathcal{M}_{\infty}$, I didn't have Stein in front of me. His definition actually does imply (via duality) that $\mathcal{M}_1 = \mathcal{M}_{\infty}$, with equal norms. The slightly tricky thing is that $T_m$ is then only clearly defined on $L^1 + X$, where $X$ is the closure of $L^{\infty} \cap L^2$ in $L^{\infty}$. But this is still enough to use the Marcinkiewicz interpolation theorem (if you dig into how it's proved) to get the norm comparison property, and so everything else still goes through.